# Add mobile menu for liquid theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, liquid, liquid-layout

In Shopify,

I have desktop menu.Here no problem on Desktop header. But mobile view doesn't show mobile menubar.

this is my desktop navbar
[image]
my mobile menu is

[image]
Then how can i create mobile menu in my mobile navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Well you simply could create a class for each of the views like so:

When display less than 768px:

```
    .mobile-only {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
        padding: 0;
    }
.desktop-only {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

When display bigger or equal than 768px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
.desktop-only {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

and then create all styles regarding this two classes where it will display in mobile or desktop.

happy coding :)